# Expectation of the reciprocal of the Gaussian tail

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ be the Gaussian distribution. For a real number $l\in\mathbb{R}$, we further denote by $N(l; \mu,\sigma^2)$ the Gaussian tail distribution, namely, $N(l;\mu,\sigma^2)$ has the density $$
p(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x \leq l,\\
C e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} & \text{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
$$ Here, $C$ is a positive number which makes the integral equal to $1$. Note that if $l>0$ and $X\sim N(l; \mu,\sigma^2)$, then $\frac{1}{X}$ is well-defined.

> Suppose $X\sim N(l; \mu,\sigma^2)$ is distributed with respect to the Gaussian tail distribution where $l>0$. What is $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]$?

I calculated $C$ to be $$
C = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\mathrm{erfc}(\frac{l-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma})\sqrt{\pi}\sigma},
$$ where $\mathrm{erfc}$ denotes the complementary error function. With this, I have $$
\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}] = C \int_{l}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\mathrm{d} x. 
$$ In the case that $\mu=0$, this integral can be expressed in terms of the incomplete $\Gamma$ function. If I am not mistaken, the integral equals $\Gamma(0;\frac{l^2}{2})/2$ in this case.

However, I was not able to solve the integral for $\mu\neq 0$.

Edit: I want to use the closest integer to $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]$ in a code. Hence, I am also happy with a good estimate or a fast algorithm that computes it (preferably, the algorithm does not actually compute the integral).

Edit2 : I would also like to add the following diagrams, that explain the behaviour of $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]$ in several regimes. [image]

In each picture, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is given in the title, the $x$-axis represents different values of $l$ and the $y$-axis is the value of $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]$. The best one is the last one: Here we have $\mu=100$ and $\sigma=2$. In this case, for small values of $l$ we always have $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]\approx 0.01$, which makes sense.

Comment: Your $C$ should also depend on $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @0XLR I don't think that it actually does but I can check again. But the hard part is the integral, not $C$.

Comment: @0XLR you were right, I edited the question.

Comment: how is your $l$ and $\mu$, which one is bigger?

Comment: @MathFail Both are possible in my case ($l \geq \mu$ or $l\leq \mu$). In both cases the problem is well-defined.

Comment: Could monte carlo be fast enough for your purposes? I'd guess you'd only have to average a sample of a few dozen realizations of the variable and then round to get the nearest integer, though you'd probably have to generate a few hundred or even a few thousand normal variables and reject those smaller than $l$ to get a final sample large enough. The original sample size will depend on $l$ and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of course.

Comment: @rajb245 Of course, this is a fairly simple way to compute the expectation. Unfortunately, this is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I wish to have a better understanding about the expectation here which might lead to much, much faster algorithms to estimate.

Comment: @rajb245 I'd also like to raise a very important point: The run-time of the Monte-Carlo method would depend on the relationship between $\mu$ and $l$. If $\mu$ is much smaller than $l$, it would take a lot of time to sample points from $N(l;\mu,\sigma)$ using rejection sampling.

Comment: @Levent i think that's right as long as you account for $\sigma$ as well, i.e., as $\left|\frac{\mu-l}{\sigma}\right|$ gets larger relative to unity, what I proposed would reject more and more of the original normal sample and indeed the algorithm would take longer.
i have a numerical idea based on changing variables to map $[l,\infty)$ to a finite interval, say $[0,1)$, and then approximating the integrand in the new variable with polynomials and integrating the polynomial. the tail decays fast enough so there's no problems there. If I make some progress I'll post an update.

Comment: @rajb245 You are right. Maybe I should have started with "Assuming $\sigma$ is constant, then..." Your idea sounds interesting, please let me know if you get something :)

Answer (score 1):

We want the following integral
$$
I = \int_{\ell}^\infty f(x) \;dx
$$
with
$$
f(x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{x}
$$
Use the following change of variables
$$
x = \sigma\tan\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)+\ell
$$
$$
dx = \frac{\pi\sigma}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right) \;dz
$$
$$
x=\ell\Rightarrow z=0,\;\;x\rightarrow\infty\Rightarrow z\rightarrow 1
$$

Which gives
$$
I = \frac{\pi\sigma}{2}\int_{0}^1 f\left(\sigma\tan\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)+\ell\right) \sec^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right) \;dz
$$
That integrand is a well-behaved enough for any numerical integration scheme of your choosing (the function is strictly positive, continuous, has finite first derivatives on the interval, and the tail decays faster than the secant blows up so the integrand is zero at $z=1$). I like the adaptive approaches where you approximate on $N$ points, then on $2N$ points, then $4N$ points, etc., and look at the differences between successive approximations; when the differences are smaller than some small tolerance value, e.g., $10^{-6}$ or so, then you can stop and error is less than the tolerance.

I'll finally note that I do not believe this would have any other closed form, and if it has some expression in terms of more exotic special functions, you'd still have to find a code that implements that special function, and under-the-hood you'd see it does various approximation techniques based on polynomial fits of the function (unlike the adaptive quadrature approach I suggested).